# search on abp commercial menu items

Tags: menuitem, abp

i am using abp commercial Angular Client and i want to search main menu items like Asp.net Zero searching capabilities. Is there a way to do this or  do you plan to add this feature within your roadmap?
thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible to add only a search input. You can use [component replacement](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Component-Replacement), but you will have to implement the template yourself.

```
import { ReplaceableComponentsService } from '@abp/ng.core';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { eThemeLeptonComponents, RoutesComponent } from '@volo/abp.ng.theme.lepton';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  template: `<!-- template here -->`,
})
export class MenuComponent extends RoutesComponent {
  // this will inherit all props and 
}

export const APP_MENU_PROVIDER = [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: switchMenus,
    multi: true,
    deps: [ReplaceableComponentsService],
  },
];

export function switchMenus(replaceableComponents: ReplaceableComponentsService) {
  return () => {
    replaceableComponents.add({
      component: MenuComponent,
      key: eThemeLeptonComponents.Routes,
    });
  };
}
```

Import and add the `APP_MENU_PROVIDER` in your `AppModule` and you will see that the menu is replaced. This, on the other hand, is not as practical as one would wish it to be. Additional customization option is planned for v4.3.